# Yeoman invoke generator by code with args

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, yeoman, yeoman-generator

I've having yeoman generator with sub generator.
I need to invoke the sub generator **via code** and I use the code below which is working, I see that the sub generator is invoked and I got the question in the terminal.

docs:
https://yeoman.io/authoring/integrating-yeoman.html

```
var yeoman = require('yeoman-environment');
var env = yeoman.createEnv();


env.lookup(function () {
    env.run('main:sub',err => {
        console.log('done' ,err);
    });
});
```

The sub generator have only one question

```
 prompting() {

    const prompts = [
      {
        name: "app",
        message: "which app to generate?",
        type: "input",
        default: this.props.app,
      },
    ];
```

...

I want to call it silently, which means to pass the value for `app` **question via code and not using terminal** and I try this which doesn't works, (I see the question in the terminal)

```
env.lookup(function () {
    env.run('main:sub',{"app":"nodejs"}, err => {
        console.log('done' ,err);
    });
});
```

and also tried this which doesnt works

```
env.lookup(function () {
    env.run('main:sub --app nodejs', err => {
        console.log('done' ,err);
    });
});
```

How can I do it ? pass the values using code (maybe like it's done on unit test but this code is not unit test... when the terminal is not invoked) 
From the docs im not sure how to pass the values
https://yeoman.io/authoring/integrating-yeoman.html

I've also found this but didn't quite understand how to use it to pass parameter to generator
http://yeoman.github.io/environment/Environment.html#.lookupGenerator
is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just do:

```
env.lookup(function () {
    env.run('main:sub',{"app":"nodejs"}, err => {
        console.log('done' ,err);
    });
});
```

and inside the `sub` sub-generator, you can find the value via `this.options.app`.

To disable the question prompt, defined `when` field inside the [Question Object](https://github.com/SBoudrias/Inquirer.js/#question) like this:

```
prompting() {

    const prompts = [
      {
        name: "app",
        message: "which app to generate?",
        type: "input",
        default: this.props.app,
        when: !this.options.app
      },
    ];

    . . .

    return this.prompt(prompts).then((props) => {
      this.props = props;

      this.props.app = this.options.app || this.props.app;

    });
}
```